# Bash and mongodb script evaluation with variables

Tags: javascript, linux, bash, mongodb, shell

Im trying to make an add user function with a combination of mongodb shell script and bash it looks like this:
(Bash)

```
function addUser {
    read -p "email(username): " email
    read -p "name: " name
    read -p "password: " password
    read -p "role (customer/merchant): " role
    salt=$(node node/getSalt)
    passHash=$(node node/getHash salt password)
    export as="var email='$email', hashedPassword='$passHash', role='$role', name='$name', salt='$salt';"
    echo $as
    mongo --nodb --quiet --eval $as adduser.js
}
```

adduser.js is just an empty script right now i need to get the variables into this script.:

```
email(username): regre
name: reger
password: ergher
role (customer/merchant): reg
var email='regre', hashedPassword='Vql40+ypE8cVoDw5jPEs0s+YbycG+pzjPVBRMIROJ/+XqiDHc7UD0aZeKY2/enKdSC3V8qMwmLJNc3D67VPHVQ==', role='reg', name='reger', salt='9QgI52o2zgIH8RORVeg1Eg==';
Tue Sep 23 00:39:03.210 SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

The script echos the value of $as which looks correct, hovever the mongodb shell script seems unable to evaluate this expression.

**How can i successfully pass this expression from bash to the mongodb shell script for evaluation?**

---

When I just call the mongo shell script like this I get no errors:

```
mongo --nodb --quiet --eval "var email='regre', hashedPassword='Vql40+ypE8cVoDw5jPEs0s+YbycG+pzjPVBRMIROJ/+XqiDHc7UD0aZeKY2/enKdSC3V8qMwmLJNc3D67VPHVQ==', role='reg', name='reger', salt='9QgI52o2zgIH8RORVeg1Eg==';" adduser.js
```

Comment: Does it help if you add quotes: i.e. `mongo --nodb --quiet --eval "$as" adduser.js`

Comment: Why are you doing this instead of using a driver or just passing a js file to mongo?

Comment: I want to dynamically call a mongodb script from bash with parameters obtained in the bash script

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the problem but is always good to pass the full path for mongo on the script.

On command line:

```
which mongo
```

Replace the word mongo on your script to the full path received on which mongo command

Comment: mongo is in my path and the script can be executed, the problem lies in the bash variable evaluation i guess

Answer (score 0):

The error is here - you are not giving any javascript code to the mongo engine for evaluation! The value after `--eval` should be a valid javascript code. But you are providing it just some plain text.

The right command would be:

```
mongo --nodb --quiet --eval "db.addUser(userAdditionDocument)"
```

and the `userAdditionDocument` would be:

```
{ user: "<name>",
  pwd: "<cleartext password>",
  customData: { <any information> },
  roles: [
    { role: "<role>", db: "<database>" } | "<role>",
    ...
  ],
  writeConcern: { <write concern> }
}
```

As you might already know, you can simply copy paste the entire `userAdditionDocument` to the command above and the code should work fine.

This entire info is available [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.addUser/).

Comment: The expression: "var email='$email', hashedPassword='$passHash', role='$role', name='$name', salt='$salt';" are valid javascript if the bash variables are evaluated? What im trying to do here is to execute the mongo shell script and init variables through the eval functionality

Comment: Ok... I get the idea of what you are trying to do. Unfortunately the idea cannot be implemented as of today. Metaphorically, you wish to make a person speak two languages when he knows only one. Have a look at this answer: http://superuser.com/questions/292818/run-a-shell-script-with-an-html-button